# AFNetworking does not returns NSString if the value is contains only digits

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I'm trying to receive a certain value in a json using AFNetworking. The value only contains digits and I want to receive it as a NSString. When I compare the received value, I get a exception (exception is also mentioned later in this post)

here is the coding producing the error.

```
 NSArray *overallGameResultsArray = [resultDictionary valueForKey:@"overall_game_results"];
        winCountDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *gameResultsDictionary in overallGameResultsArray)
        {
            NSString *userId = [gameResultsDictionary valueForKey:@"winner_user_id"];
            NSString *winCount = [gameResultsDictionary valueForKey:@"win_count"];

            if ([winCount isEqualToString:@"0"])
            {
                NSLog(@"0 wins");
            }

        }
```

I don't get the exception if the "if comparison" is commented.  The win_count only consists of digits in the jSON response.

Following is the exception error I'm getting.

```
2012-10-10 15:41:35.086 FMB[3549:c07] -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7230af0 2012-10-10 15:41:35.086 FMB[3549:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7230af0'
*** First throw call stack: (0x1638012 0x1345e7e 0x16c34bd 0x1627bbc 0x162794e 0x11e03 0x20583 0x1fab4 0x245053f 0x2462014 0x24527d5 0x15deaf5 0x15ddf44 0x15dde1b 0x26997e3 0x2699668 0x28d65c 0x2512 0x2445) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is either with the JSON you're receiving or the  request you're making. Without these more details it's not possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you'll have to do :

```
NSString *winCount=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[gameResultsDictionary valueForKey:@"win_count"]intValue];
```

With this, you get the number value into the winCount NSString, and then you can use isEqualToString method

Answer (score 1):

The exception is thrown because you *expect* an object to be an `NSString` but actually is an `NSNumber`, so you try to call `isEqualToString:` on the `NSNumber` which doesn't implement the method.

Since you know that `winCount` is always a number and apparently the JSON deserializer that `AFNetworking` uses box the numbers in the response into `NSNumber` objects, you could easily grab a string out of the object like this:

```
NSString *winCount = [[gameResultsDictionary valueForKey:@"win_count"] stringValue];
```

Now you have a string representation of your number and you can therefor perform `isEqualToString:`

Also note that a more elegant solution might be to receive your objects as `id`s, find their class and do a comparison based on the class determined.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you use JSON. Then the type of the object is determined by JSON encoding. If there are `"` around, it's a string. If it's a number and you want string there, change how the data is encoded on the server.

However, in this context, using a number makes more sense. You should change the implementation in the following way.

```
NSNumber* winCount = [gameResultsDictionary valueForKey:@"win_count"];

if ([winCount intValue] == 0) { //this would actually work for both NSNumber and NSString
    NSLog(@"0 wins");
}
```

Comparing numbers using string comparison is always a hint that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Why does this answer have so few upvotes?? This is the *only* correct answer. Why the hell would you convert two numbers to a string to compare them?